# In Kendo UI using angularJS, How to avoid overlapping of Statusbar and navigation bar in iOS 7 and above

Tags: ios, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am newbee to Kendo UI.

I am using AngularJS and Kendo UI for developing iOS app. How should I avoid overlapping of Stats bar and navigation bar?

Here is How I added navigation bar but it gets overlap with stats bar

```
<body kendo-mobile-application k-hash-bang="true" ng-app="MobileAppModule" platform="'ios7'">
    <kendo-mobile-layout  k-id="'default'">
    <kendo-mobile-header >
        <kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
            <kendo-view-title></kendo-view-title>
        </kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
    </kendo-mobile-header>
</kendo-mobile-layout>


<kendo-mobile-view id="abc" k-title="'Home'" k-layout="'default'">
    Hello world
</kendo-mobile-view>
```

1. How should I avoid overlapping of Stats bar and navigation bar on iOS 7 and above?
2. How to set colour of status bar?

I know how to do it using markup language from link: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/everything-hybrid-web-apps-need-to-know-about-the-status-bar-in-ios7

Answer (score 1):

Everything you mentioned can be done using the [cordova-plugin-statusbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-statusbar)

```
 <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm"/>

 <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />

 <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
```

Comment: I have added it it config.xml file but still status bar overlaps on navigation bar.